Configure Spring batch
I'm trying to create Spring Batch process to read Oracle DB and use the data to send out some emails. For Batch repo I want it to use H2 database as I don't want to add new tables into our main database.
So far I have not managed to get the process running my job. It just silently closes after launch.
I checked out the gs-batch-processing sample that works normally, but as soon as I extend the configuration class with DefaultBatchConfiguration, it stops executing the job and does nothing.
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration

What is the missing part, that would enable again the job's automatic start in this case?

Found the solution - you need to declare @BatchDataSource bean:
  @Bean("batchDataSource")
  @BatchDataSource
  public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
      .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
      .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
      .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
      .generateUniqueName(true)
      .build();
  }


If, and it seems you have, your springbatch application is booting up fine while able to connect to both dbs, then you just need to point your springbatch application to h2 datasource:
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "h2DataSource")

But it seems you're using DefaultBatchConfiguration. So you can't use '@EnableBatchProcessing'.  In that case, you define your own job repository:
@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(h2DataSource());
    factory.setDatabaseType("h2");
    factory.setTransactionManager(batchTransactionManager());
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public DataSource h2DataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
        setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
}


@EnableBatchProcessing is now discouraged by spring batch if you are using spring boot 3.
But as usual - after asking the question I stumbled into solution myself. :)
